# Node.js Вернуть результат функции в родительскую функцию

Tags: node.js, функции

```js
module.exports.request = (userId) => {
    db.get(userId).then(value => {
        return value;
    });
}
```

`return value` вернет значение в стрелочную функцию `value => {}`. Но как этот `return` сделать возвращением функции `(userId) => {}`

Comment: Что-то у меня большое подозрение что это очередной дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/190728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант...

```js
module.exports.request = async (userId) => {
  let value
  try {
    value = await db.get(userId)
  } catch(e) {
    value = null
  }
  return value;
}
```